# Dynamic Footer MPDF

Tags: php, footer, mpdf

I'm using mdpf and php to generate a PDF. I need to create a different footer every time I use the tag pagebreak.

My code is something like this (and it's not working this way)

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4');
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('First Article','O');
$html = 'Lots of text';
.
.
.
$html .= "pagebreak"; (this is a html tag)
$html .= 'More lots of text';
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('Second Article','O');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
print $mpdf->Output();
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear. What different footer do you want to set? and why not just set footer for each page using `SetHTMLFooter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *flush*  the content with `WriteHTML`, then set a new footer.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4');
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('First Article','O');
$html = 'Lots of text';
.
.
.
$html .= "pagebreak"; (this is a html tag)

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html); //flush

$html .= 'More lots of text';
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('Second Article','O');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

print $mpdf->Output();
```